# createAsyncThunk: Error: addCase cannot be called with two reducers for the same action type

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-thunk

This error occurred when I connect actions to **extraReducers**
My code is

```
export const fetchCountries = createAsyncThunk(
  `country`, 
  async (organizationId: string) => {

export const saveCountry = createAsyncThunk(
  `country`,
  async ({ } => {})

const regions = createSlice({
  name,
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: builder => {
    builder.addCase(fetchCountries.pending, isFetching);
    builder.addCase(fetchCountries.rejected, error);
    builder.addCase(fetchCountries.fulfilled, (state, action) => {});

    builder.addCase(saveCountry.pending, isFetching);
    builder.addCase(saveCountry.rejected, error);
    builder.addCase(saveCountry.fulfilled, (state, {payload}) => {});
```

and if I run I get this error:
`Error: addCase cannot be called with two reducers for the same action type`

Answer (score 65):

This happens because in my actions there is few *AsyncThunks* actions with the same ***typePrefix***.

So it must have different names:

```
export const fetchCountries = createAsyncThunk(
  `getCountry`, //<------ this first argument (name) must be unique
  async (organizationId: string) => {

export const saveCountry = createAsyncThunk(
  `postCountry`,
  async ({ } => {})
```

Comment: Thanks for helping reduce time required to find a thunk copy-paste mistake :)

Answer (score 6):

In my case, the same error message was show, but it was a different mistake:

```
.addCase(setAddress.pending, (state, action) => {
    state.setAddressStatus = 'Pending';
})
.addCase(setAddress.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
    state.setAddressStatus = 'Fulfilled';  
})
.addCase(setAddress.fulfilled, (state, action) => { // I repeated fulfilled 
    state.getAddressesStatus = 'Rejected';
    console.error(action.error);
})
```

It took me some minutes to find the problem, may help someone.

Answer (score 4):

On CreateAsycThunk you have mentioned both the string of the same name it should be like this

```
export const fetchCountries = createAsyncThunk(
  `country`, 
  async (organizationId: string) => {

export const saveCountry = createAsyncThunk(
  `saveCountry`,
  async ({ } => {})

const regions = createSlice({
  name,
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: builder => {
    builder.addCase(fetchCountries.pending, isFetching);
    builder.addCase(fetchCountries.rejected, error);
    builder.addCase(fetchCountries.fulfilled, (state, action) => {});

    builder.addCase(saveCountry.pending, isFetching);
    builder.addCase(saveCountry.rejected, error);
    builder.addCase(saveCountry.fulfilled, (state, {payload}) => {});
```

Comment: how your answer differs from mine?

Comment: It looks like the difference is both are named \`country\` in the question and here one is labeled \`country\` and the other \`saveCountry\`

Answer (score 2):

createasyncthunk has two main parameters, one of type string and the latter callback function which has api and thunk as paramters.
You are likely to be pardon if having a single asyncthunk in your slice, which has "" as data, but if you have two or more asyncthunks then checks will be made on each thunk, if two or more of them has similar "" or "identical" names then you will get disturbing error. "createAsyncThunk: Error: addCase cannot be called with two reducers for the same action type"

Answer (score 1):

If your createAsnyncThunk is using the same typePrefix  like

```
const updateEventsCal = createAsyncThunk(
EVENTS_CAL_UPDATE, // using an existing typePrefix say EVENTS_CAL_ADD
async (data) => {
 }
```

This will throw the same error.

Answer (score 0):

make it this way

```
const  {pending,fulfilled,rejected} = fetchCountries
    builder.addCase(pending, isFetching);
    builder.addCase(rejected, error);
    builder.addCase(fulfilled, (state, action) => {});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are having this error because you are attempting to add multiple asyncthunks with the same typePrefix ie the first argument in the createAsyncthunk. Each asyncthunk must have a unique typePrefix. To resolve this you simply create a unique typePrefix for each createAsyncthunk

```js
export const fetchCountries = createAsyncThunk(
  `fetch-country`, 
  async (organizationId: string) => {

export const saveCountry = createAsyncThunk(
  `save-country`,
  async ({ } => {})
```

You can also have the same error message when you try to add multiple reducers for the same action type using the addCase function ie

```js
const regions = createSlice({
  name,
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: builder => {
    builder.addCase(fetchCountries.pending, isFetching);
    builder.addCase(fetchCountries.rejected, error);
    builder.addCase(fetchCountries.fulfilled, (state, action) => {});
    
    builder.addCase(fetchCountries.fulfilled, (state, action) => {});
 
    builder.addCase(saveCountry.pending, isFetching);
    builder.addCase(saveCountry.rejected, error);
    builder.addCase(saveCountry.fulfilled, (state, {payload}) => {});
```

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem,have a look below:

```
//api to get data customers
export const getCustomers = createAsyncThunk('/api/users/customers',async() =>{
    ...
});
//api to add customer
export const addCustomer = createAsyncThunk<User,{ user: User, token: string }>('/api/users/add_customer', async ({ user, token }) => {
    ...
});
```

i got the problem cuz i wrote this path **/api/users/customers** in frist and second asyncthunk, to solve it ,just need to rename it, in my case, first i didn't change it **/api/users/customers** and second **/api/users/add_customer**